# How to know if a field is already added to Layout ? (using Apex Metadata API)

Tags: apex, metadata-api, page-layout, summer-17

I was wondering if we can check if a field is already added to layout, add it otherwise. As I used the metadata API for layouts, noticed that if we include a single component in Metadata.DeployContainer (which is existing in current layout), whole deployment fails.

It's great to,

1. Have ability Check the component/field existence before adding to container
2. Pass a parameter to ignore failed ones
3. Have reasons to know why it fails  in the callback response

Is it possible using the Apex Metadata API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such Boolean parameter available in Apex Metadata API. But we have this in Tooling API. In Force.com Tooling API we have a Boolean parameter `IsCheckOnly` which Indicates whether the asynchronous request compiles the code without making any changes to the organization (true) or compiles and saves the code (false). Please check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_containerasyncrequest.htm

Comment: There is a checkonly option for the metadata API, too.